# Recovery attempt without disc

Tags: windows-7

I have a Presario CQ57, Windows 7, I got a free upgrade to Windows 10.  after awhile it was running slow, so I tried a factory reset (system recovery), I didn't get recovery discs with it, but did recovery anyway. Now all I get is "An operating system wasn't found.  Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart"  I don't know what to do, or what I did wrong

Comment: Download Windows 10 ISO directly from Microsoft.  Boot to ISO using your chosen method.  Reinstall Windows 10.  Your factory reset clearly failed, your original installation is permanently gone, my suggestion will work

Comment: @Ramhound You should post this as an answer. However, will his Windows 7 COA key work when he installs 10 again?

Comment: @oldmud0 I already have. He doesn't need to use the COA due to how Windows 10 licensing works.  Which I have explained several times in numerous answers

Comment: @Ramhound Allow me to remind you that this is a user with *one rep*. How is he going to know the pains you have taken to answer this question if you have not even linked to or explained how to find any of your answers beside a hand-waving "Google is your friend"?

Comment: @oldmud0. That would mean I would have to spend time looking for the most appropriate answer, but my comment was towards your question, not the authors

Answer (score 1):

Because it says "An operating system is not found" doesn't mean there isn't one. While you claim you did "factory reset" you also said "system recovery" which are two different things. If you did factory reset you should go back to Windows 7. But if you did recovery it would have gave you two options: "Keep my files" or "Remove Everything." If you do not want to lose your files try all the steps I list. If you want to remove everything and do a fresh install of Windows 10 or 7 do 1-3 and proceed with installation (use the *same* Microsoft account you used with the upgrade, else it will not activate).

1. Download the Windows 10 ISO by using using the Media Creation Tool from their [site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) with another computer.
2. Either burn it to a disk find directions online or as I recommend put it on a flash drive with more than 3.5 GB (at the moment, minimum depends on ISO file's size). Use the tool called [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to put it on the flash drive. Now you may have to try and repeat till this boots correctly in the next step, but From my Google Search it seems your device is UEFI and GPT. Usually UEFI will have a HP symbol right away at boot-up. If that doesn't boot try BIOS and MBR, then UEFI and MBR. You select these in the rufus drop down menu.
3. Boot up to it. If it is UEFI, often times you can press Esc to give you a menu. Else you may have to try out some F1-F12 keys. Or choose what it says if it shows the keys to press. You can also go to bios and change the boot order to the device you are using.
4. At a successful load into the Installation, you first want to go to "Repair your computer." You will be lead to a screen with multiple buttons. Try these in sequential order to help you (I tried ordering them from easiest to hardest)
5. Navigate to something "Fix Startup." Try it, if fails, move on, if succeed, restart computer.
6. Navigate to Command Prompt.
7. Run the command `bootrec /scanos`. If it says it found 1, there is an OS, skip to 9. If it is 0, don't get your hopes down, because this often lies (to me atleast).
8. Run the command `diskpart`. In Diskpart then run `list volume`. If it says something that is identifiable to your OS you are in luck ("NTFS...", "Boot", "System", About the same partition size, etc...) and you should continue trying to fix it. Note the assigned drive letter it was given. If not assigned a drive letter (e.g. "C") run `sel vol <``number of what it is>`. Then assign the letter with `assign letter=c` (replace the letter c with whatever). If not I am sorry, If you need your files you should do some research on how to recover it, if it is still there. Then type `exit`
9. Run this command `bootrec /fixboot`. If you had 1 or more OSs show up when we scanned then run `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. If success, restart. If not, next step.
10. Assign a drive letter to the volume if not already, as we did in step 8. Run this `dir c:` (replace letter). If it lists "Windows" in the directory, you may be able to continue recovery. If not you have to reinstall it. If you want to recover your potentially lost files, you are going to have do research on your own. If it does list it, run `bcdedit c:\windows` (replace letter). If it works, restart your computer. If not, Sorry.

Good Luck!